# PHP $_GET not working

Tags: php, forms, joomla, get

Heres my url

localhost/sistema/altera-valores.php?tarefa=2&id_registro=1464&id_edicao=6

heres my code to get the variables

```
<?php $tarefa = $_GET[tarefa]; $Id = $_GET[id_registro]; $id_produto = $_GET[id_produto];  ?>
```

Now i really dont know whats happening if i type :

```
<?php echo $tarefa; ?>
```

nothing happens any ideas?

I migrated this site from online to localhost, is joomla 1.5 system and mod rewrite is on

Comment: try `<?php $tarefa = $_GET['tarefa']; $Id = $_GET['id_registro']; $id_produto = $_GET['id_produto'];  ?>` with quotes

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Joomla, you shouldn't access the `$_GET` superglobal directly.  Use [`JRequest`](http://docs.joomla.org/JRequest/1.5) instead, as it will also clean the variables for you with a variety of `get` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your keys should be in quotes eg: `$tarefa = $_GET['tarefa'];`

Answer (score 0):

Using $_GET is really not the way to do it. You may expose your database to a very easy SQL injection.

Since you are getting some integers there, use [JRequest::getInt](http://docs.joomla.org/JRequest%3a%3agetInt/1.5).  This will be something like:

```
$tarefa = JRequest::getInt('tarefa');
```

Also I would **strongly recommend** having a look at the [Secure coding guidelines](http://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines).